# Dijit.form.DateTextBox issue with applying class to body

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have been fighting with getting the Dijit.form.DateTextBox working inside of a div.  I have found that if I apply the "claro" class to the body tag that it will work just fine.  Although, I don't want the claro class overwriting my other styles.  Also, I don't have access to my body tag on all of my pages due to MVC.

Here is what I have:

```
<html>
   <head>
        <style type="text/css">
          body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
        </style>
        <script src="dojo/dojo.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
            dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");

        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
        />
    </head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="claro">
            <input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" value="2005-12-30" dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="claro">
            <input type="text" name="date2" id="date2" value="2005-12-30" dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" />
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what problem do you have when you do it this way?  I'm going to guess that the popup doesn't have proper styling, since it may get populated elsewhere in the DOM.  I suspect Dijit requires the theme to be set on the BODY for this reason.

Comment: Well, it overrides my css styles that I have set previously in an imported css file.  After investigating further, the DOM element that is created for the calendar, is a child element of the body.  I just can't believe that you would have to apply the class to the whole body.  I was looking for a way to just apply a class to the element that is created so that it (the body class) doesn't override my previously inherited css.

Answer (score 0):

Just had him implement the Calendar feature that comes with jQueryUI.  It is much more straight forward.  I see Dojo as more of an Application Framework instead of just using certain widgets for web pages.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, by default all dojo pop-ups are appended to the BODY (weird).

I found a work around. Just copy the tundra/calendar.css to calendarFix.css and remove all .tundra or .claro references from it. For example, consider this fragment:

```
:   
.tundra .dijitCalendarDecrease {
 background-position: top left;
} 
.tundra .dijitCalendarIncrease {
 background-position: -30px top;
}
.tundra .dijitCalendarContainer {
 font-size: 100%;
 border-spacing: 0;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 0;
}
:
```

to

```
:   
.dijitCalendarDecrease {
 background-position: top left;
} 
.dijitCalendarIncrease {
 background-position: -30px top;
}
.dijitCalendarContainer {
 font-size: 100%;
 border-spacing: 0;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 0;
}
:
```